# how to replace special characters in any query on mysql by function method?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which does lot of

```
   REPLACE... REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(strip_tags(p.products_description),'\t',''),'\n',''),',',' '),'\r','') ...
```

Is there any easier way of handling it from mysql itself?

My code does not look good and complicated.

A simpler mysql function would be much better.

Comment: If it has to be `MYSQL` only, then remove the `PHP` tag from your question. It's misleading. :/ If it can be in `PHP`, then you could use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't look nice if you do it in MySQL because mysql `replace` allows to replace only one string and not an array.

You should do such replaces in PHP using `str_replace` function and you will be able to replace many strings